# generate SourceMap based on JavaScript using source-map in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, source-maps

no matter what I do the map is empty on map.toString().

```
let path = require("path");
let content = fs.readFileSync(".\\" + file, "utf8");
let filename = path.basename(outFile)
const { code } = js(content);

fs.writeFileSync(outFile, content);
fs.writeFileSync(outMinFile, code);

let gen = new sm.SourceMapGenerator({
    file: filename,
    sourceRoot: "./",
});

gen.setSourceContent("CMS.Layout.js", content);

fs.writeFileSync(outMap, gen.toString());
```

results in:

```
{"version":3,"sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":"","file":"CMS.Layout.js","sourceRoot":"./","sourcesContent":[]}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `sm` set?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone at the top of the file. var sm = require("generate-source-map");

Comment: its not in the question shouldn't presume people know the lib you're using how your loading it.. considering the question is about why `new sm.SourceMapGenerator` doesn't work

Comment: also, how it initialized the `js` variable ?


On my side I tested the usage of `generate-source-map` but no luck with ES6 (?) syntax: the strings with backquote throw an error. Not surprising, as `generate-source-map` has been published 6 years ago, but I don't know which equivalent library I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced source-map with generate-source-map. much easier and it worked on first try.

```
let path = require("path");
let content = fs.readFileSync(".\\" + file, "utf8");
let filename = path.basename(outFile)
const { code } = js(content);

fs.writeFileSync(outFile, content);
fs.writeFileSync(outMinFile, code);

let fl = {
    source: content,
    sourceFile: filename
};

let map = sm(fl);

fs.writeFileSync(outMap, map.toString());
```